# Script error in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, error, arctoolbox

I have a problem when using some geoprocessing tools in ArcGIS 10.2, such as "Merge". The message that appears is `an error has occurred in the script on this page`. I've seen this is a quite common error, but I've tried all the options I've seen on different blogs and StackExchange answer and nothing has worked.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Establishing Internet Explorer as the default browser.
2. Establishing Microsoft Edge as the default browser.
3. Replacing the "Stylesheet" folder´s files as indicated on this link https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011008
4. Repairing ArcGIS through the Desinstallation Procedure, but at some point this message appears -see pictures- (and can´t find this file) so I can´t continue.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That error message you are getting during the install process needs the original installation disc. How was ArcMap installed on your machine? You need to contact your IT support to either download the 10.2.2 iso from myESRI or get them to give you the install DVD. That will allow the repair process to continue.